# drupal single page Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: views, 6

I am having a problem I really can't figure out. I am running a drupal mobile website using mobile tools and I have also boost installed on drupal. 
Now the mobile website works fine on m.domain.fr BUT ONE page doesn't work. It returns a Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) but all other pages ar ok. 
This page is a view and I can access it just as expected in Views Editor, I have normal preview, but i can't access this page from web.

Any help would be welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Are you able to access your server's logs (Apache & PHP error logs) ?

Comment: No, I have not access to them but I finally found the problem. I had a unsupported function in the template file for this views, that's why it didn't work. I have replaced the fonction and it's fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the source of the problem, it was a unsupported PHP function in the view template. As I replaced this function, the page worked normally.